# Redirect issue with MAMP, XAMPP

Tags: macos, iis, xampp, mamp, windows-7-x64

I've been creating a website on my pc. I installed php, turned on iis, and use dreamweaver and everything works seemlessly, I can test on localhost perfectly. But i want to work on the website elsewhere, like on my laptop or a mac desktop. But i've noticed using the packaged softwares like XAMPP for my windows laptop and mamp for the mac desktop has some problem with going to the next page. Let's say I have two pages, on page 1 after clicking submit it should take you to page 2, works perfectly fine on my pc but on the laptop and mac it just straight up fails to move on, it just redirects back to page 1. Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Also, my laptop won't turn on IIS service, i go to optionalfeatures.exe and turn it on, it takes a while and then says something like "an error occurred, some features not enabled". Which is why i was forced to use XAMPP.